# Make Phone Calls on Adobe AIR on Android

Tags: android, air, adobe

I'd like to make a phone call via an AIR application on android. I know you can do this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(tel:555555555));
```

But I want control of the phone call.

The aim is that the app missed calls a selected number. So it calls, waits for it to ring for 1 second and then cuts the call. But with the method above, the app has no control of the phone call.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, there is no way that you can 'control' the call flow using AIR apps. The best you can do is invoke the native call application using 'tel' protocol, which you have mentioned.